# comparision of two table having same field?

Tags: mysql

I have to table.
Both table has nric field.

I want to select the nric field which does not inside in table.

si_isccourse table

```
ID NRIC
1  456
2  457
3  458
```

si_results table

```
ID   NRIC
1    456
```

si_isc_class table

```
ID NRIC
1  456
2  457
```

my results like this

```
ID NRIC
3  458
```

this is my sql query

`SELECT DISTINCT(isc.isc_nric) from si_isccourse iscLEFT JOIN si_results re ON re.re_nric=isc.isc_nric LEFT JOIN si_isc_class cla ON isc.isc_nric!=cla.isc_class_nric WHERE (isc.isc_second_choice='FPS') AND ( re.re_year IN('2010','2009')) AND ( re.re_code IN('VETCA1','VETCA2')) AND isc.isc_nric!=cla.isc_class_nric ORDER BY re.re_mark desc`

I want to get data not in si_isc_class table.
I want to select data from si_isccourse and compare with si_results and not in si_isc_class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT first.*
FROM first
LEFT JOIN second ON(first.id = second.id)
WHERE second.id IS NULL
```

Comment: there is no matching records from third table

Comment: hi . This is correct. I tried. I get my desired values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the position of the tables.

some thing like

```
...
FROM si_isc_class ..
Left JOIN ....
```

Then you will get the desired value.

Comment: Actually I don't want to select from si_isc_class. I want to select data from si_isccourse and compare with si_results and not in si_isc_class